# How to pass both the id and the value of an input to a JS function in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I tried hard to fix this issue but I'm not a JS programmer, so I didn't succeed yet. I need to write the right code in my HTML to pass the id and the value of an input to a JS function. Here is my JS code:

```
    <script>
    function live_update(id,str) {
      if (str.length==0) { 
        document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("live_update").style.border="0px";
        document.getElementById("live_update").style.display="none";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML=this.responseText;
          document.getElementById("live_update").style.class="bg-light";
          document.getElementById("live_update").style.display="block";
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","profiles.php?act=live_update&u_key={u_key}&id="+id+"&q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

And here is my HTML code

```
<input type="text" onfocusout="live_update(document.getElementById('{id}').value,document.getElementById('quantity').value)" name="quantity[]" id="9" value="{quantity}" class="sm-input-40"/>
```

Comment: Why you passing the id ? Where is that `{id}` coming from ?

Comment: You don't really have to support IE6 anymore. No one uses IE6, and if you remove that it will make your code simpler and make it easier for you to debug it, better because you said you are a beginner.

Comment: I need to pass both the id and the value of the input to a PHP function. I need the id to change specific record in the DB

Comment: Where is that `{id}` coming from ?

Comment: Your function logic is not correct. you are not passing `args` correctly.

Comment: I want to pass the id of the input which is number 9 and the value of the same input after I write something in it. Clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple example that you don't need to overcomplicate things, in this case you can just past element to function to `onfocusout` handler. I've commented your block code logic and made example for you to capture value, and ID of that element..
hth

```js
function live_update( el ) {
  var str = el.value ;
  /*
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("live_update").style.border = "0px";
    document.getElementById("live_update").style.display = "none";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("live_update").style.class = "bg-light";
      document.getElementById("live_update").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  */
  console.log( 'Value: ', el.value, ', ID: ', el.id )
//  xmlhttp.open("GET", "profiles.php?act=live_update&u_key={u_key}&id=" + id + "&q=" + str, true);
//  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocusout="live_update( this )" name="quantity[]" id="9" value="{quantity}" class="sm-input-40" />
```

Comment: Awesome but I need to send this request via AJAX to PHP file and return back a response. What you commented is the AJAX code which does this function. Excuse me if I'm wrong. I'm 0% in JS. I'm just a PHP programmer.

Comment: I would like to thank you so much for kind and prompt help. I used parts of your code and combined them with mine to get both id and the same input value to the PHP through the JS function. Thanks again, you made my day :))))

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code, I see that you use `{id}`. I do not know what that is, but there is a way to do it differently. Instead of `{id}`, actually instead of that entire `document.getElementById`, you can just pass in `this`, which will count as the element of the element the code is calling. Also, I see a little mistake you made, here.

```js
document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML=this.responseText;
document.getElementById("live_update").style.class="bg-light";      // Here
document.getElementById("live_update").style.display="block";
```

You cannot change the class with style. You have to use `classList`.
Change it to this:
document.getElementById("live_update").classList.add("bg-light");

Hope I helped you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in JS you cannot use a numeric id selector. It will cause an error.

As everyone has mentioned already, they don't know where the {id} comes from. Obviously it comes from some PHP end template / html script. But that is absolutely barbaric. Your field should have ID, you bind your event to the id or use classes if you have multiple fields. Then you detect the onfocusout event on that field as listener and handle its content accordingly. If you have some custom variable requirement, then you can use attributes in the input field.

Your input field is also having [] which indicates, that there are more fields like this? But you have id value.. Strange. I think for this question to be fully answered, you need to provide some more context on where is this script used and how.

**Javascript:**

```
// NOTE: Numeric ids should be avoided imo.
const nine = document.querySelector('#nine')

// Detect onfocusout event on field #9
nine.onfocusout = (e) => {
    
    let
    
        // Get the value of the field:
        nine_value = nine.value,
        
        // Get the {id} attribute:
        nine_id = nine.getAttribute('data-id'),
        
        // Get the {u_key} value from somewhere??
        nine_ukey = nine.getAttribute('data-ukey')
    
    // Check if the value is empty:
    if (!nine_value) {
        document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("live_update").style.border="0px";
        document.getElementById("live_update").style.display="none";
        return;
    }
    
    // As it seams, that your error checking is done above only.. yes there should be more of it..
    // Then we can continue with the ajax call using fetch api:
    fetch('profiles.php?act=live_update&u_key=' + nine_ukey + '&id=' + id + '&q=' + nine_value).then(r => r.json().then(d => {
        
        // This is checking the backend readystate thingy:
        if (d.readyState == 4) {
            // The return payload comes as d variable. So if you send back JSON,
            // which is handled above, then your response text looks about like this: d.responseText
            document.getElementById("live_update").innerHTML=d.responseText;
            document.getElementById("live_update").style.class="bg-light";
            document.getElementById("live_update").style.display="block";
        }

    // Errors are however handled like this:
    })).catch(err => console.log('Error: ' + err))
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Numeric ids should be avoided, so we use #nine instead and you can put your {id} into an attribute.-->
<!-- Also since you didnt provide further context about the script, then I will be removing the [] from quantity. -->
<input type="text"  name="quantity" id="nine" data-id="{id}" data-ukey="{u_key}" value="{quantity}" class="sm-input-40"/>
```

I hope I didn't miss anything, I coded it fairly blindly. Check out [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [custom attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).